# VAO memory issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to draw a thousand of objects with OpenGL (3.3). 
I'm using one VAO for each object and I think it's the problem.

Isolating the problem for test I notice that, in the code below, from point 0 to point 1 the process memory increases 800MB.

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum initStatus = glewInit();
assert(initStatus == GLEW_OK);

// point 0
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
}
// point 1
```

What's the approach to handle this problem?
I know it's possible to share one VAO for multiple meshes, but what to do when one of this meshs is removed or has its vertices changed??

Comment: Your question seems... confused. I don't understand what the problem is with "what to do when one of this meshs is removed or has its vertices changed??". Perhaps you should just try to put everything in a single VAO and then ask about the problems you encounter when doing so.

Comment: Usually you won't have to change meshes very much. For example you draw a square, changing the size of it should be done in shaders using transformation matrices. Same with 3D squeletal animations. And even if you have objects with different number of vertices, you can draw a subset of all vertex to be drawn and consider that an "object"

Comment: It's not my case. I'm writting an editor and my meshs has its geometry changed all the time :(

Comment: Then find a way to reduce the number of mutable meshes or find another approach. Either way, this problem is much too broad for this site.